# Signed time limited Google Storage Urls format

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have tried by creating Google Cloud Storage Signed Urls in below format, its working fine -

```
http://<my-bucket-name>.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/<my-object>?GoogleAccessId=GOOGMYACCESSKEY&Expires=1382521793&Signature=<signature>
```

As Amazon S3 support this format and Google also working with it.

And at one Google developer page for creating signed urls with [Google Cloud Storage](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#Signed-URLs), found Urls format as -

```
http://google-testbucket.storage.googleapis.com/testdata.txt?GoogleAccessId=1234567890123@developer.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1331155464&Signature=BClz9e4UA2MRRDX62TPd8sNpUCxVsqUDG3YGPWvPcwN%2BmWBPqwgUYcOSszCPlgWREeF7oPGowkeKk7J4WApzkzxERdOQmAdrvshKSzUHg8Jqp1lw9tbiJfE2ExdOOIoJVmGLoDeAGnfzCd4fTsWcLbal9sFpqXsQI8IQi1493mw%3D
```

Which one is correct way?

What disadvantages can cause of not using **storage** in place of **commondatastorage**?

Thanks,

Neelam Sharma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one is the new, correct way. `commondatastorage` was the previous name for accessing cloud storage, which still works and has no disadvantages, but you should still upgrade to the new, shorter domain name if possible.

You can find up-to-date information about request URIs on the [Google Cloud Storage Request URIs](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/reference-uris) page.